# Vaadin Combobox - New Item

Tags: java, combobox, vaadin8

I am writing Code in Java and I am using the Vaadin 8 extension.

I have a Vaadin Combo Box and it works well. But I would like to not only select items from my Combo Box, but also select the written input. That means I would like to use the Combo Box as a Drop Down Menu and also as an Text Edit Field.

After some research I think it is not possible to get the value of the Combo Box after writing something into it. The Text Edit Field is only for searching in the Drop Down Menu. 
If I type something that is not part of the Drop Down Menu the value is null.

But it seems possible to add new Items to the Combo Box Drop Down Menu with the method setNewItemProvider.

There are some examples out there that use the old method getNewItemHandler but they dont seem to work for the newest Vaadin version 8. The method setNewItemsAllowed is no longer part of Vaadin 8.

Can anyone provide an example with the new method setNewItemProvider for Vaadin 8?

Comment: Being able to search the items by writing into the combobox is literally the default behaviour of the comboBox. As linked in Gergely's answer, you could turn this behaviour on and off using `comboBox.setTextInputAllowed(boolean)`, but it is on by default. Check out [these examples](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-combo-box/java-examples)!

Comment: Sorry I think I havent made myself clear. I not only want to search the items but also just extract a string that is not part of the items via .getValue() that means I also want to use the ComboBox as TextEdit field in addition.

Comment: you can't use it to directly edit existing items, but you can use it to create new items.  [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/components/components-combobox.html) is a good example implementation of `comboBox.setNewItemProvider()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly do what you planned, but you have a much simpler solution there.

There is a specific function for **turning combobox editable**: [javadoc](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.6.4/com/vaadin/ui/ComboBox.html#setTextInputAllowed-boolean-)

Comment: Thx for the link. But in the description of the link I can read: "user can enter text into the field to either filter the selections or enter a new value if new item provider or handler is set". I still need an example for item provider.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not have a machine at hand right now. I think a simple `addValueChangeListener` (+ a `setNewItemsAllowed` before) will do the job, no need to deal with itemproviders by hand. Let me know if I am wrong and I will set it up later.

Comment: setNewItemsAllowed is no longer part of Vaadin 8